# How to get networkVersion with ethers

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, networkid

If you write `window.ethereum` into the browser console it will print a proxy object that looks like this:

```json
window.ethereum: Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
<target>:
​​
    ...

    isMetaMask: true
    networkVersion: "1662582417739"
​​
    ...

<handler>: Object { deleteProperty: deleteProperty() }
```

As you see, there is a `networkVersion` property which is the equivalent of the `web3.eth.net.getId()` line of code (of course when you are using web3.js)

But when you are using ethers.js, I do not see any method that provides `networkVersion`. Sure you can get `networkId` but not `networkVersion`.

Is there any method to get `networkVersion` using ethers itself? Or we should fallback to using `window.ethereum.networkId` ?

Im actually surprised that there is no documentation on this. This `networkVersion` is the only way you can get the contract address from its json file (**Contract.networks[networkVersion].address**). Is this on purpose? A design decision made by the ethers team?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this tutorial for using Ethers.js library to interact with the Ethereum blockchain and search for "networkversion".

https://jetsoanalin.github.io/EthersJsTutorialJetso/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. It is better to include the main idea in the answer and leave the link for the additional details.

Comment: In that tutorial the author is using `window.ethereum.networkId` which I knew from the start. Is that the standard thing to do? or should ethers library itself provide a method to get it through it (as web3.js does with `web3.eth.net.getId()`)